# Converting factor to numeric with correlation matrix

Tags: r

I have loaded a csv with the variable Tickets which imports as factors. Converting this variable to a numeric produces the wrong min and mean. Adding character to the numeric fixes issue but then cannot be used with CorrelationMatrix.

```
$ Tickets        : Factor w/ 12 levels "4.00", "7.00",..
```

I have converted the factors to numeric but when I run the summary function, I see the wrong min and mean. 
I then tried converting to a character and then a numeric which produces the correct mean, but now I cannot produce a correlation matrix.

```
var_1<-as.numeric(Data$Tickets)

var_2<-as.numeric(as.character(Data$Tickets))

Cut1_Data <- data.frame(var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5)

CorrelationMatrix <-cor(Cut1_Data)
corrplot(CorrelationMatrix, method="circle")
```

`var_1` produces min = 1.00 and mean = 8.318 which is wrong but I can run the Correlation Matrix

`var_2` produces min = 2.00 and mean = 4.862 which is right but I cannot run the Correlation Matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNSym.png)

Comment: When you say you "cannot produce a correlation matrix", what do you mean? Does R crash? Is there an error? A warning? (What does it say?) A result but you don't think it's correct? Something else?

Comment: And the code you show for the correlation matrix uses a variable called `Cut1_Data` which isn't mentioned anywhere else in your code... is that your data frame, the same one you call `Data` elsewhere? Are you actually putting the numeric version in the data frame, or are you keeping it as a separate object called `var_2`?

Comment: @Gregor Thank you,  yes, I added the variable into the dataframe which includes var_2, code above. When I run the correlation matrix on this, it produces all "?".

Comment: Can you share `dput(Cut1_data[1:10, ])` so we can see the object you're working with and the classes in it?

Comment: structure(list(var_2 = c(5, 9, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4, NA, NA, 2), var_3 = c(95, 
71, NA, 132, 112, 130, 741, NA, 220, 476), var_4 = c(486, 
295, NA, 786, 375, 500, 670, NA, 278, 657), var_5 = c(496, 510, 
NA, 577, 617, 322, 460, NA, 350, 619)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame") @Gregor

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of missing values. Try `cor(Cut1_data, na.rm = TRUE)` to ignore the missing values.

Comment: `CorrelationMatrix <-cor(Cut1_data, na.rm = TRUE)`

Error in cor(Cut1_data, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: How about `cor(na.omit(Cut1_data))`

Comment: Thank you that worked! @Gregor